# Bind the all data in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following code in default.aspx.cs:

```
DataSet dsvehicle_info = new DataSet();

for (int i = 0; i < dsvehicle.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dsvehicle_info = cls.ReturnDataSet("RetriveData_Alias1",
        new SqlParameter("@Field", "vehicle_no,lat,lon"),
        new SqlParameter("@TblNm", "current_gps_data left join device_master on device_master.id=current_gps_data.id"),
        new SqlParameter("@WhereClause", "where current_gps_data .id='" + dsvehicle.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString() + "'"));

}

vehicle_info.DataSource = dsvehicle_info;
vehicle_info.DataBind();
```

When I run this then it will bind only the *last* record.
How can you bind the all the data?

Comment: The data you are binding to will consist of whatever is returned in the last iteration of the loop because dsvehicle_info gets overwritten for every iteration so you end up with whatever was in it in the final iteration.

Comment: okie..so how can i bind that all record?

Comment: Either retrieve it all in one go, not in a loop, or keep adding to your data rather than overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

is there some reason you can't add it like this?

```
DataSet dsvehicle_info= new DataSet("VehicleInfo");
dsvehicle_info.Tables.Add(dsvehicle.Tables[0]);
```